# Iptables to mask one host of a subnet to different NIC

Tags: linux, iptables

I could use some help with this. I don't even know how to get started despite being familiar with iptables.

I have a gadget, with a static IP address 10.0.0.2/24. This is what it is and I cannot change it.  My laptop used to have just one NIC. I was able to connect to the public internet and this gadget (which does not need to access any other devices but my laptop) by just plugging it into my development network and giving my laptop NIC a secondary address 10.0.0.1 and plugging the device to the same switch as my laptop. Not ideal but it worked.

Now I had to move to another development network, the IP range of which is .... (suspenseful music) ....  10.0.0.0/24. And 10.0.0.2 is in its DHCP range occupied by another device.

I have now obtained another network interface card (eth1) for my laptop and given it an IP address of 10.42.42.1.

Basically what I need to do is some iptables magic to make it so that when I access for example 10.42.42.2, this traffic when exiting eth1 gets IP address 10.0.0.5 for example and is passed to 10.0.0.2 in eth1, and when the gadget responds and eth1 receives the response, it will be passed to my host laptop as if coming from 10.42.42.2.

I probably need SNAT/DNAT rules here but how should I set them up?

H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a task for `iptables`, `network namespaces` suit better the problem,

```bash
# Create network namespace gadget
ip netns add gadget

# Put device eth0 in gadget namespace
ip link set eth0 netns gadget

# Configure network in gadget namespace
# # Bring up ifaces
ip netns exec gadget ip link set lo up
ip netns exec gadget ip link set eth0 up

# # 10.0.0.0/24 address on eth0 
ip netns exec gadget ip address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev eth0

# Now gadget pinging should work...
ip netns exec gadget ping 10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about namespaces completely. I used to use them all the time to do some weird Openstack routing, but it has been a while.

Comment: Any idea how to connect a single relay process to both namespaces? (Python). Or should I just skip the whole thing and build a temporary solution with one program listening and feeding to an unix domain socket, and another listening in the default namespace and relaying the data forward?

Comment: So you want to put the gadget on the development network via your laptop...

Comment: Basically I need to connect to it to poll data, then convert the resulting data to a format acceptable by the app that needs to process the sensor data, and push it there.  I have done this with other "gadgets" without the IP address clash.  But as the "app" is on the public Internet, my relay needs to access both the gadget and internet. 

I will probably just build something quick and dirty with temp files etc. until I can change the device IP address.